# Assigning Middleware To Routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I want to let only authenticated users access a certain page in my application. After reading the documentation I found out this can be done using middleware. I assigned the auth middleware to the route which I want to protect, but I can still access it even if I am not authenticated.

```
Route::get("add","Clubs@add",['middleware' => 'auth', function () {}]);
```

Comment: Have you read this page https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication ?

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for this syntax.

```
Route::get('profile', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@show'
]);
```

So for your case, it should look like this.

```
Route::get('add', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'Clubs@add'
]);
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. I managed to solve the problem by calling the middleware from the constructor of the controller. But it should work even if I assign it in the routes.

Comment: Yes, that should work. What version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: I can't think of any reason the syntax I posted would not work. This is probably a silly question because it seems like you know what you're doing, but did you replace the route path and controller you use in the example I posted so it looks like the second example I just added?